# Operational Error: no such column: users_userscore.id

Tags: django, django-models

For my web application, I have two apps, one is **morse_logs**, the main app; second, is the **users** app, which mainly handles the users details and authentication, etc.

At the moment in my **users** app, I have a **UserProfile** model, which has one variable which is **description**, and now I am struggling to add one more variable **score** to user, so that each user will have one score variable/field to store their scores, and the user's score will be updated after certain actions in morse_logs game1.html and morse_logs/views.py (the main app).

I am really not familiar with modelling and create table, columns these sort of stuff...

And when I do migrations, it gives me error like Operaional Error: table "users_userscore" already exists...

I tried deleting the migrations py files, but it didn't work

all my code are on github: https://github.com/phl6/morse_log

***So, my question is how can I edit my model file so I can have a score variable/field for each user which this variable can be updated in the morse_logs(main app).***

**users/model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    #score = models.CharField(User, max_length=10, default=0)


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)


class UserScore(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True, null=False, db_index=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the model"""
        return self.score
```

**morse_logs/views.py**

```
@login_required()
def game1(request):

    if request.user and not request.user.is_anonymous:
        user = request.user
    #else:
        #Throw some raised exception here as the user is not valid...

    """The Game 1 page"""
    val1 = request.GET.get('ans1', '')
    res = "Incorrect"

    user_score = UserScore.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

    if val1 == 2:
        #user's score declared in model increase 5points
        #display correct and 5 points added to user
        res = "Correct"
        user_score.score += 5
        user_score.save()
    else:
        #user's score declared in model has no point
        #display incorrect and 0 point added to user
        res = "Incorrect"

    return render(request, 'morse_logs/game1.html', {'result': res})
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding primary_key parameter in user one to one fiel, comment out date field and cast the return value as str.

```
class UserScore(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of the model"""
        return str(self.score)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it is clear that the database columns are already created from a previous migration.

To fix this, you could

1. If you have deleted all the migration files, run `python manage.py makemigrations` to recreate the migration files. If you have all the migration files, skip to 2.
2. Run a fake initial migration by running `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

Running this command checks whether the database tables and columns to be created in the migration already exist and if they do, it is going to skip creating them and will run the migration without throwing an error.

You can check the official django documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#django.db.migrations.Migration.initial